# Converting Infix to postfix with >1 digit

Tags: java

I have a method that can convert an expression from its infix notation to its postfix notation, but I don't know how to handle numbers greater than 9.

For example,
If I have 12-(5+3) I wouldn't want it to be expressed as 1253+- but 12 53+- (or a similar form) instead.

What I have:

```
private void postfix(){
        String result = "";
        LinkedStack<Character> stack = new LinkedStack<Character>();
         for (int i = 0; i < expression.length(); i++){
             char c = expression.charAt(i);
             if (Character.isDigit(c)){
                    result += c;
             }
             else if (c == '('){
                    stack.push(c);
             }
             else if (c == ')'){
                    while (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '('){
                        result += stack.pop();
                    }
                    if (!stack.isEmpty() && stack.peek() != '('){
                        result = "Invalid Expression";   
                    }
                    else{
                        stack.pop();
                    }
                }
             else if(isOperator(c)){ 
                 while (!stack.isEmpty() && weight(c) <= weight(stack.peek()))
                        result += stack.pop();
                 stack.push(c);
             }
         }
        postfixed = result;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify this part of your code:

```
if (Character.isDigit(c)){
    result += c;
}
```

If the expression is "1234", you'll just calculate 1+2+3+4 instead of treating 1234 as a single number.

What you can do instead is to collect consecutive digits into a `String`. Then, convert the string to an Integer using [Integer.parseInt()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))